# "tensor not found in the checkpoint" when evaluating the re-tuned inception-v3 model using TF-slim

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I evaluated the re-tuned inception-v3 model with my dataset using [eval_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) in TF-slim, I got an error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights not found in checkpoint
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_7 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_7/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_7/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Then I printed all tensors' names in the orignal inception-v3 checkpoint and the re-tuned checkpoint, then compared these tensors with tensors inception_v3.arg_scope, I found that some tensors in the checkpoint were different from that in the inception_v3.arg_scope:

```
"InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2a_3x3" in the inception_v3.arg_scope
"InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2a_5x5" in the checkpoints
```

Has the architecture of inception_v3 changed before? How to solve this problem? Retrain the whole inception-v3 model with inception_v3.arg_scope rather than re-tuning?

Comment: Please add this  `tf.reset_default_graph()` to python script.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tf.reset_default_graph()` to python script it will fix issue like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it didn't work. Maybe I inserted tf.reset_default_graph() into the wrong place. Can you show me where I should add tf.reset_default_graph()?